# Values not appeared in drop down

Tags: java, spring

there is an issue in my web application, the below code i wrote for entire application and it is working fine..but not in this case.
I am using the correct variables name in JSTL, my query is also running fine and produces the required result that i want, but still those values didn't appeared in the drop down .. i am even not able to figure it out

can anybody help me to sort out this

```
<td>
    <span id="store_${i}"></span>
    <f:select class="form-control"  path="boqList[${i}].organizationCode" id="storeId${i}"                                      onchange="chekeAvailibiltyAtStore(this.value,'${b.itemCode}','${b.itemUnit}','${i}')" required="true"> 
        <f:option value="">Select Area Store</f:option>
        <c:forEach  items="${areaStors}" var="as" >
            <f:option value="${as.organizationCode}">${as.organizationName}</f:option>
        </c:forEach>
    </f:select>
</td>
```

Inside controller

```
mav.addObject("areaStors", areaStoreDAO.findAll());
```

Inside Service (Query working Fine)

```
 public List<ErpAreaStore> findAll() {
        String query = "SELECT  ORGANIZATION_CODE "
                + "           , ORGANIZATION_NAME "
                + "  FROM XXAP_AREA_STORE "
                + "  ORDER BY ORGANIZATION_CODE ASC ";
        MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        List<ErpAreaStore> inventoryOnhands = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(query, param, new RowMapper<ErpAreaStore>() {
            @Override
            public ErpAreaStore mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNo) throws SQLException {
                ErpAreaStore areaStore = new ErpAreaStore();
                areaStore.setOrganizationCode(rs.getInt("ORGANIZATION_CODE"));
                areaStore.setOrganizationName(rs.getString("ORGANIZATION_NAME"));
                return areaStore;
            }
        });
        return inventoryOnhands;
    }
```

POJO

```
public class ErpAreaStore implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int organizationCode;
    private String organizationName;

    public int getOrganizationCode() {
        return organizationCode;
    }

    public void setOrganizationCode(int organizationCode) {
        this.organizationCode = organizationCode;
    }

    public String getOrganizationName() {
        return organizationName;
    }

    public void setOrganizationName(String organizationName) {
        this.organizationName = organizationName;
    }

}
```

see the below screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: The code looks OK. Try debugging, verify that it's the same dropdown that you're populating in JSP and checking on UI.

Comment: Also add `<jsp:useBean id="areaStors" scope="request" type="java.util.List"/>` at the beginning of your JSP in order to ensure that the list is passed correctly from Controller to JSP page processor. If `areaStors` is passed this statement should not affect your application logic, otherwise you'll see an exception on page load.

Comment: @naXa kindly provide the implementation of ur suggestion in my existing code, thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`<jsp:useBean>` tag](https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-useBean-action) at the beginning of your JSP. It's a straightforward test that the `areaStors` list is present. Example:

```jsp
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<jsp:useBean id="areaStors" scope="request" type="java.util.List"/>

    <!-- ... -->
    <td>
        <span id="store_${i}"></span>
        <f:select class="form-control"  path="boqList[${i}].organizationCode" id="storeId${i}" onchange="chekeAvailibiltyAtStore(this.value,'${b.itemCode}','${b.itemUnit}','${i}')" required="true"> 
            <f:option value="">Select Area Store</f:option>
            <c:forEach  items="${areaStors}" var="as" >
                <f:option value="${as.organizationCode}">${as.organizationName}</f:option>
            </c:forEach>
        </f:select>
    </td>
```

Comment: good one...i really don't know how it is going to work..bcz i used your snippet first time in my project and rest of that posted code is working fine in other places, but what makes this page so special..any ways thanks so much thanks so much

Comment: @Zia have it solved your issue? are dropdowns populated with values now?

Comment: yup it is... i don't knw ..how but i got my expected result thanks so much naxa